# Filters may not have any gaps within the composite key querying FieldHistoryArchive

Tags: soql, field-history

Given this query:

```
SELECT Id 
   FROM FieldHistoryArchive  
   WHERE FieldHistoryType = :fhType AND parentId = :parentIds 
   ORDER BY Id LIMIT 10
```

I get the runtime error:

```
Filters may not have any gaps within the composite key
```

yet [per the SOQL doc on `FieldHistoryArchive`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.field_history_retention.meta/field_history_retention/field_history_soql.htm), there are no gaps in the composite key - `FieldHistoryType` is specified and then `ParentId`

### Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the misleading (*it references "filters"*) error message is the `ORDER BY Id` clause in the SOQL

Per the [FieldHistoryArchive Object reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_fieldhistoryarchive.htm?search_text=fieldhistoryarchive), if you are going to use `ORDER BY`, it has to be:

```
FieldHistoryType ASC,ParentId ASC, CreatedDate DESC
```

Correcting the ORDER BY (or removing it) resolves the error.